# How do I use the Unity methods in Quickly's python code?

Tags: unity, application-development, python

How do I use the Unity methods in Quickly's python code.  All I want is an example of a few methods, like quicklists, notifications, indicators, etc.

Comment: This video might also be useful:
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wqGfsgz1Sl4

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I suggest you look at this link:

[Unity Developer](http://developer.ubuntu.com/resources/platform/unity/)

Just choose the category you're interested in.